# Can GNU Stow use a stow directory that is a symbolic link?

Tags: symlink, stow

Consider this script.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p target
mkdir -p mydir/package/
touch mydir/package/file

ln --symbolic mydir mylink
file mylink

stow --verbose --dir=./mylink --target=./target package

file target/file
```

The output is

```
mylink: symbolic link to mydir
LINK: file => ../mydir/package/file
target/file: symbolic link to ../mydir/package/file
```

Before running `stow`, it looks like this:

```
.
├── mydir
│   └── package
│       └── file
├── mylink -> mydir
└── target
```

After running `stow`, on `mylink`, I expected it to look like this:

```
.
├── mydir
│   └── package
│       └── file
├── mylink -> mydir
└── target
    └── file -> ../mylink/package/file
```

However, instead it looks like this:

```
.
├── mydir
│   └── package
│       └── file
├── mylink -> mydir
└── target
    └── file -> ../mydir/package/file
```

It seems that the `stow` command resolves the realpath of the package directory, so instead of pointing to `../mylink/package/file` it points to `../mydir/package/file`.

This makes sense for avoiding too much indirection, but it happens silently and may not always be desirable. Is there a way to work around this behavior?

**Edit:** As per request, I will describe an example use case
where resolving the realpath is inconvenient.

Symbolic links are sometimes [used for compatibility](https://wiki.debian.org/RenamingPackages#Compatibility_symlinks).
Debian even [talks about this in official policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#symbolic-links).
Often the target is a single file,
but [sometimes it is a directory](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=47799)
.
I happen to have a few hundred on my system in `/usr/share/doc/` alone:

```
$ find /usr/share/doc -xtype d -type l | wc -l
325
```

The default behavior of `stow` is fine
as long as the symlink target doesn't get moved.
But sometimes the desired targeted directory does get moved.
For example, on Debian, the `vim-runtime` package
installs files under /usr/share/vim/
in a directory that depends on the version,
such as `/usr/share/vim/vim64` for version 6.4.
However, the package would also [update a symlink](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=369124)
at `/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent` that pointed to the current version.
This means that a symlink pointing to, say

```
/usr/share/vim/vim64/doc/cmdline.txt
```

would break when the next release of Debian upgraded it to

```
/usr/share/vim/vim70/doc/cmdline.txt
```

but a symlink to

```
/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/doc/cmdline.txt
```

would work in both versions.

Since `stow` uses the absolute canonical path of the stow directory,
an invocation like

```
stow --dir=/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent --target=./my-vim-docs doc
```

would result in symbolic links like, e.g. this:

```
$ file cmdline.txt
cmdline.txt: symbolic link to ../../../../../usr/share/vim/vim64/doc/cmdline.txt
```

not like this:

```
$ file cmdline.txt
cmdline.txt: symbolic link to ../../../../../usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/doc/cmdline.txt
```

(The motivation for using `stow` on `vimcurrent/docs`
is to be able to mingle my own vim notes alongside symlinks to the current documentation.)
Note that the `vimcurrent` compatibility symlink is
[no longer present in current Debian distributions](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/v/vim/unstable_changelog),
[though it may be in others like Arch Linux](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/15597);
I'm not sure.
In any case, here's a script that gives the general idea for vim documentation:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p target
ln --symbolic /usr/share/vim/vim80 vimcurrent
stow --verbose --dir=./vimcurrent --target=./target pack
file target/dist
```

Output is:

```
LINK: dist => ../../../../../usr/share/vim/vim80/pack/dist
target/dist: symbolic link to ../../../../../usr/share/vim/vim80/pack/dist
```

Hypothetically, `stow` could have a flag called, say, `--no-realpath`,
so the output would look something like this instead:

```
LINK: dist => ./vimcurrent/pack/dist
target/dist: symbolic link to ./vimcurrent/pack/dist
```

For other examples of compatibility symlinks that change with each version,
here are two more I know of on my laptop:

```
$ file /usr/share/go
/usr/share/go: symbolic link to go-1.10
$ file /usr/share/mscore
/usr/share/mscore: symbolic link to mscore-2.1
```

To address the symlink-points-to-symlink case:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p target
mkdir -p mydir/package/
touch mydir/package/file
ln --symbolic mydir mylink
ln --symbolic mylink mylink2
namei mylink2
```

produces:

```
f: mylink2
 l mylink2 -> mylink
   l mylink -> mydir
     d mydir
```

and then:

```
$ stow --verbose --dir=./mylink2 --target=./target package
$ file target/file
```

produces:

```
LINK: file => ../mydir/package/file
target/file: symbolic link to ../mydir/package/file
```

whereas

```
$ stow --no-realpath --verbose --dir=./mylink2 --target=./target package
$ file target/file
```

would produce this:

```
LINK: file => ../mylink2/package/file
target/file: symbolic link to ../mylink2/package/file
```

So in the hypothetical `--no-realpath` behavior it would treat the stow directory as a regular directory.

This feature would be applicable in a scenario where

1) the stow directory has to be a symlink, and

2) it is desirable to preserve that link in the generated symlinks.

While I don't consider the lack of this feature a great deficiency of `stow`,
I hope that this example clarifies the potential usefulness
of not always resolving canonical paths.

Comment: Please could you give an example use case where avoiding this indirection would be helpful?  What if `mylink` instead symlinked to `mylink2` which in turn symlinked to `mydir`?  How should Stow decide whether it should create symlinks pointing to `../mylink/package/file` or `../mylink2/package/file` or `../mydir/package/file`?

Comment: @AdamSpiers I hope that helps somewhat. I could put this on the Github issue tracker, too, if you'd prefer.

Comment: Thanks @Nathaniel. Yes please that would be helpful!

Comment: @AdamSpiers Done! https://github.com/aspiers/stow/issues/11#issuecomment-507073811

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For now, there's no way.

Internally, `stow` find absolute canonical path of given path by using [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) to move into the path, then use [getcwd()](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#getcwd) function from POSIX module, which is the Perl interface for [POSIX getcwd()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html), to get the absolute path name.

As POSIX specified, the path name shall contain no components that are `.` or `..`, or are symbolic links.

Comment: Suggestions on how to fix the implementation to handle this correctly are very welcome. Pull requests are even more welcome! :-)  For reference, the issue has been reported here: https://github.com/aspiers/stow/issues/11

Comment: @AdamSpiers I was just having this issue. Anyhow a big appreciation for your hard work on `stow`, it's a very nice tool!